# Failed to create a session, as response has been committed

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my web app I have form-login for users and basic authentication for server-to-server API calls. Basic auth flow is stateless but form-login is not.
When some one requests API with basic auth I got following warning in logs

```
Failed to create a session, as response has been committed.
```

After some research I found few topics with suggestion to use NullSecurityContextRepository or set `<http create-session='never' />`
I cannot use these solutions since it will break the form login flow.

How can I disable session creation only in basic auth flow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Spring Security 3.1, you can configure [multiple `<http>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-and-basic) elements in order to differentially protect URL patterns. This should allow you to have different session creation strategies in place for different http elements.

Please check the above link related to the namespace configuration of multiple http elements using both form and http-basic authentication for different ant-patterns. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot use this solution since I must support same url patterns use both basic and form auth.

Comment: What is your full use case and how do you differentiate between normal request and API call? You may also be able to handle your requests based upon the http method they use. Please provide a bit of insight about your problem then may be I or anyone else in the community would be able to help you better.